# How to read Stack Overflow notifications without marking them as read?

Tags: support, notifications, api

I have a browser script that uses my current session to open websites such as stackoverflow.com and collects list of all the notifications. From what I can tell, the equivalent of the following request is being made to read the list of the notifications:

```sh
curl 'http://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox?_=1448923335094'
    -H 'Cookie: [..]'
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
    -H 'Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01'
    -H 'Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/'
    -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
    --compressed
```

The problem is that this request marks notifications as read.

Is there any parameter that I can add to the query that would not mark this request as read? Is there another endpoint that I could query (using my current browser session) to query the same information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackexchange.com/users/inbox/153435 should work, where 153435 is your network account ID.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an equivalent for achievements?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.